# What parts of a .NET solution causes compilation to be slow?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, msbuild, compilation

My employer has a solution with 14 projects, and coincidentally, it takes precisely 14 seconds to compile the entire application.  This makes it difficult to make changes and re-compile--lots of wasted time.  What are things in a .NET application I can look for to make compilation quicker?  Or may I ask, what tools are the best to troubleshoot this sort of thing.  (To see what's happening with msbuild.exe)

**Solution Details:**

- strongly typed datasets w/ Reporting Services
- WCF services
- combination of C# and VB.NET projects
- one web application project
- resources (resx files) all over the place
- Enterprise Library (I can get specific if you need me to)
- Microsoft's UIProcess application block for wizard navigation
- Microsoft AJAX Control Toolkit
- PdfSharp

Please ask if you need more details.

Comment: 14 seconds?? My gosh what will you do while you wait :p

Comment: Well, he is MacGyver. He should be able to compile the whole solution in 14 milliseconds. :-P

Comment: Hanselman had a few podcasts about building the ultimate dev machine, and one thing he pointed out is that compilation is disk intensive, so the cheapest solution is often to buy very fast disks. I think he got SSDs.

Comment: @Ray, what percentage of a business day are wasted when you take 14 seconds * 250 compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up building, unload the projects you're not working on. In the Solution Explorer, right click a project and click "Unload Project". You can select multiple projects and unload them all at once. When you build, unloaded projects will not be built.

If a solution contains a lot of projects, you're almost certainly only working on a few of them at any given time. If you're working on them all at once, you need to take a look at the way you work.

This is not the same as removing the project from the solution. When you need to change/rebuild an unloaded project, it's easily to simply reload it.

Comment: This handy extension - Solution Load Manager - helps with only loading projects you need: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2

Comment: unloading the projects reduced it from 14 to 9 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to rebuild the entire solution every time you make a change? Would rebuilding the current project be enough? that might speed things up a bit.

I work on a solution that has almost 300 separate projects, and takes about 2 minutes to do a full build, but when i am working i only build the project i am currently working on, saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

When referencing other VS projects, ensure you have "copy local" set to false unless you require it for a specific reason.

You could create another solution specific to the projects that you are working on.

It's not a long time though!

Comment: It's in the Properties panel for each Project or Assembly reference.

Answer (score 2):

- If your are using source control with local files e.g. SVN it is worth to disable anti-virus on your code directory.
- Set *Copy to Output Directory* to *Do not copy* if you cannot do that use *Copy if newer*
- If possible remove all pre/post build events
- If you have WebSite project switch to WebApplication
- For unloading and loading projects you could use [Solution Load Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2).

Comment: Our projects didn't have a local data file (from what I got from an article regarding that setting).. for that Copy to Output Directory setting.. at least I couldn't find it.  Can you explain how to get that option?  What steps would I perform?

Answer (score 2):

Compilation is sometimes disk bound, especially for .Net applications. It will go faster on a solid state drive.  If you want to test this theory, put your code into [RAM disk](https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows) and compile it.

Comment: what are the steps necessary to compile a .NET application using RAM Disk?

Comment: I am marking another guy's as the answer until I can get this to work and reduce the compile time to under 9 seconds.  His reduced mine from 14 to 9 seconds, which is better.

Comment: Step #1, install a suitable RAM disk. The linked one is free and works well enough. Move your source code to the RAM disk. (It will look just like another ordinary drive on the computer) Be sure to be using source control and frequent check ins, RAM is volatile. The temporary files of compilation are written to the obj folder, the final objects are written to the bin folder. So all important reads and writes are to the working folder of your app (i.e. the same folder as your sln file)